# Video not play in fullscreen in iframe tag

Tags: html, video, iframe

I want to play video in full screen. I used iframe tag to play video in popup.

But it is not playing in fullscreen. It puts padding from all sides. How can i play video in full screen?

i used this code for display in full screen but it is not working.

```
<iframe id="popup_video" width="600" height="300" src="videopath" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen webkitAllowFullScreen mozAllowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Can you please add your html code in code snippet?

Comment: in youtube video it is display in full screen ...but from local video it is not playing in full screen @NiravJoshi

Answer (score 0):

Add these attributes to iframe: `<iframe … allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true">` (no IE support though)

Comment: allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" try this

Comment: which browser are u using ?

Comment: firefox and chrome

Comment: If you're unable to do this (because the video is already embedded somewhere without your access) you have to go with the workaround (new window in full size).

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
video
</title>
<style>
.iframe-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16x9 */
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.iframe-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class='iframe-container'>
  <iframe src='videopath' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you talking about making the video fullscreen to fit your browser window size? or
making the video fit the iframe container?